# how to count words in a data frame based on a list of dictionary terms in r

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm trying to perform a dictionary count of terms in a factor of strings.

I have a factor called Names.  An example below:

```
[1] GP - Hyperion Planning Upgrade
[2] Application Support Renewal
[3] Oracle EBS upgrade 11.5 to 12.1
[4] Bluemix Services
[5] Cognos 11 Upgrade
```

I also have a list of dictionary terms called `terms`:

```
[1] "IBM"     "Oracle"     "SQL Server"     "Cognos"     "Azure"
```

What I need from R is to create a dataframe from the list of `terms` and a total count of each team from the `Names` factor.  Example:

```
         term       count
1        IBM         3
2        Oracle      6
3        SQL Server  0
4        Cognos      2
5        Azure       9
```

Of note: the term can be in multiple times in a single name.  it counts as once.

I would like to ask if anyone has any examples on this that I could derive from.  Thanks.

Comment: I might miss something but how is your input related to the output? I don't see IBM in `names`, so where does the `3` in the output come from?

Comment: sorry, just typing an example.  assume the factor I put in the question here is a subset of the full size of the factor.  didn't want to put thousands of lines in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (changing the vector `Names` a little bit and assuming that you want case-insensitive matches):

```
# input
Names <- as.character(Names)
Names
#[1] IBM GP - Hyperion IBM Planning Upgrade IBM"
#[2] Application Support Renewal"               
#[3] Oracle EBS upgrade 11.5 to 12.1"           
#[4] Bluemix Services IBM"                      
#[5] Cognos 11 Upgrade"  

terms <- c("IBM",     "Oracle",     "SQL Server",     "Cognos",     "Azure")
vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern', SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
df <- +(vgrepl(tolower(terms), tolower(Names))) # case insensitive

df
#     ibm oracle sql server cognos azure
#[1,]   1      0          0      0     0
#[2,]   0      0          0      0     0
#[3,]   0      1          0      0     0
#[4,]   1      0          0      0     0
#[5,]   0      0          0      1     0

colSums(df)
#    ibm     oracle sql server     cognos      azure 
#     2          1          0          1          0 

data.frame(count=colSums(df))
#           count
#ibm            2
#oracle         1
#sql server     0
#cognos         1
#azure          0
```

## [EDIT2]

```
df <- data.frame(count=colSums(df))
df <- cbind.data.frame(terms=rownames(df), df)
df
#                terms count
#ibm               ibm     2
#oracle         oracle     1
#sql server sql server     0
#cognos         cognos     1
#azure           azure     0
```

Comment: this is for case insensitive only, e.g., if `Names` contain `ibm` or `IBM` or `iBM` for all it will be considered a match.

Comment: I'm trying now.  give me a minute.  THanks much!

Comment: ok.  perfect.  how do I pivot it vertically so I can push into a dataframe?

Comment: sorry, the x value is not in one of the columns. it's the row name.  can you move it over?  I need to plot them.

Comment: close enough for me.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example avoiding regex in favor of `match`:

```
names <- c(
"GP - Hyperion Planning Upgrade",
"Application Support Renewal",
"Oracle EBS upgrade 11.5 to 12.1",
"Bluemix Services",
"Cognos 11 Upgrade")

terms <- tolower(c("IBM", "Oracle", "SQL Server", "Cognos", "Azure"))

## Split your names on whitespace and match each token to the terms
counts <- lapply(strsplit(tolower(names), "\\s+"), match, terms, 0)

## index the terms using the match indices and table it
table(terms[unlist(counts)])

cognos oracle 
     1      1
```

Comment: on your last line, can you push to a data frame? vertically?

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(terms[unlist(counts)]))`

Comment: I appreciate it, however, I already started implementing the other guys solution.  Thanks much tho.  still get a +1